# How to calibrate realsense D435 camera to use ORBSLAM2

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I need help for camera calibration for ORB-SLAM2. I have Intel RealSense D435 camera. I have calibrated it by using Intel dynamic calibrator. But, when I am running ORBSLAM2 algorithms, I can not map anything. ORBSLAM2 algorithm is running properly but I cannot see anything in camera window. Do I need to calibrate my camera separately to use ORB-SLAM?

Comment: This camera is factory calibrated.  You should take the supplied calibration information and edit the appropriate orbslam configuration YAML.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Does that mean I have to go through separate stereo/monocular calibration for orbslam? Like they have explained that here: http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, since all the parameters should be provided by Intel.  I can't remember exactly where they list it, though.